# Disable a Tab in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, tabs

We have a Tab controlled rendered with CSS, using `<li>`.

Once rendered, we have this:

```
<div class="innertabs" id="tabbar">
<ul>
    <li id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_SIS_ICMS_IntranetWeb_Modules_Person_TabCasePlanYJ_CasePlan_TabInterventionsYJ_liOrders" class="" disabled="disabled">
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_SIS_ICMS_IntranetWeb_Modules_Person_TabCasePlanYJ_CasePlan_TabInterventionsYJ_lnkOrders" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$SIS_ICMS_IntranetWeb_Modules_Person_TabCasePlanYJ_CasePlan$TabInterventionsYJ$lnkOrders','')">Orders</a>
    </li>
    <li id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_SIS_ICMS_IntranetWeb_Modules_Person_TabCasePlanYJ_CasePlan_TabInterventionsYJ_liProgramActivityList" class="" disabled="disabled">
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_SIS_ICMS_IntranetWeb_Modules_Person_TabCasePlanYJ_CasePlan_TabInterventionsYJ_lnkProgramActivityList" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$SIS_ICMS_IntranetWeb_Modules_Person_TabCasePlanYJ_CasePlan$TabInterventionsYJ$lnkProgramActivityList','')">Program/activity list</a>
    </li>
    <li id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_SIS_ICMS_IntranetWeb_Modules_Person_TabCasePlanYJ_CasePlan_TabInterventionsYJ_liProgramActivityDetail" class="current">
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_SIS_ICMS_IntranetWeb_Modules_Person_TabCasePlanYJ_CasePlan_TabInterventionsYJ_lnkProgramActivityDetail" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$SIS_ICMS_IntranetWeb_Modules_Person_TabCasePlanYJ_CasePlan$TabInterventionsYJ$lnkProgramActivityDetail','')">Program/activity details</a>
    </li>



</ul>
```

Problem is, when we set a tab to disabled, the text of the tab (on the actual tab bit that you click) goes disabled - but, still remains clickable.

We are trying with this code:

```
private void TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityDetails_OnCreateProgram()
    {
    //    ShowProgramActivityDetailPanel();
    //    TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityList.Visible = false;
    //    TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityDetail.Visible = true;
    //    liProgramActivityList.Disabled = true;
    //    liOrders.Disabled = true;

        ShowProgramActivityDetailPanel();
        TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityList.Visible = false;
        TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityDetail.Visible = true;
        TabCasePlanInterventionsOrders.Visible = false;
        //TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityList.PopulateForm();

        liProgramActivityList.Attributes.Add("class", "");
        liProgramActivityDetail.Attributes.Add("class", "current");
        liOrders.Attributes.Add("class", "");
        liProgramActivityList.Disabled = true;
        liOrders.Disabled = true;


        if (CurrentAssessment!= null)
        {
            TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityDetail.CurrentAssessment = CurrentAssessment; 
        }

        TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityDetail.ChangeToCreateMode();   

        if (CurrentCasePlan!= null)
        {
            TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityDetail.CurrentCasePlan = CurrentCasePlan;
            TabCasePlanInterventionsProgramActivityDetail.ChangeToCreateMode();   
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to not make it clickable?

Comment: what library of controls does this tabstrip come from (custom, telerik, etc)

Comment: It's custom, I think, and it looks like the <li>s are being rendered with CSS to look like tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the list item is disabled instead of the child controls.

Try cycling through the child controls of liProgramActivityList, e.g. liProgramActivityList.Controls and disableing all those as well.

Comment: But will this still not allow me to move to the disabled tab? We want to remain on the current enabled tab - and now allowing the clicking of any other tabs.

Comment: Actually, thanks! I see what you're doing. The child is a LinkButton, and we have disabled that. Works. thanks.